# Android: Which is the best way to repeat an action through a service without repeating alarm manager?

Tags: android, service, timer, alarmmanager, repeat

I'd like to know Which is the best way to repeat an action through a service without a repeating alarm manager.

I start a service with alarm manager ("not repeating" alarm manager) because I need that this service will not be interrupted by android.

This service receives some parameters while it is active and should elaborate by repeating certain actions. If I use the repeating alarm manager the service will not properly read them.

I tried to use the class "timer", but after a while Android stops it and the service don't do anything.

Is there a way to maintain a service active while it uses a timer without Android stops everything?

Many Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using a service marked as sticky and starts on boot?

Comment: Android can "interrupt" whatever it wants, whether you like it or not. For that matter, *users* can "interrupt" whatever they want, whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 1):

you can make your service a foreground service  like this :

```
final int myID = 1234;
//This constructor is deprecated. Use Notification.Builder instead
        Notification notice = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Started  Alarm", System.currentTimeMillis());

        //This method is deprecated. Use Notification.Builder instead.
        notice.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Alarm.", "Please wait...", pendIntent);

        notice.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
        //notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;


        startForeground(myID, notification);
```

then android will stop your service only if there is no other way and your service is high priority

the only thing is that you must a a notification

Comment: I don't huderstand how this code help me. Can you give me an example?

Comment: call it in your oncreate method then  implement the variable "Notification notification;" (for the whole task),  when you want your service to stop being in foreground call "stopForeground()"